# How to get image width and height dynamically while zooming in android?

Tags: android

I used the below method to find the image width and height dynamically.But,I got the same value while zoom in and zoom out an image.I also used like this to retrieve the iamge width:- float width=imag.getWidth(). For this also the same value is displayed.I set the image width as 300dp in my xml file.

```
image.setOnTouchImageViewListener(new OnTouchImageViewListener() {
                @Override
                public void onMove() {
                    RectF rect = image.getZoomedRect();
                    currentZoom = image.getCurrentZoom();               

                                Drawable d = image.getDrawable();
                    Bitmap bmp = ((BitmapDrawable)d).getBitmap();
                    currwidth = bmp.getWidth();
                    currheight = bmp.getHeight();

                               calculate(currwidth);
    MarginLayoutParams params = (MarginLayoutParams) animImag.getLayoutParams();
                 params.leftMargin =(int)calculate(currwidth); params.topMargin =                     (int)calculate(currwidth);
                animImag.setLayoutParams(params);

                }               
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to try image.getMeasuredWidth and height. for Proper size of Image.

Comment: This image.getMeasuredWidth ahd height method is not displaying the correct width and height.When i zoom slowly it will show 900 as its width.But the width value will increase slowly.For example,I fixed the image width as 300dp in xml.If i zoom in means it will show as 330,350 and so on.